# 403 Forbidden Error in Urban Airship when uploading .p12 file for iOS

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

I have registered an account in urban airship and created an application in it. I am following the below link.

http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html

But when I try to upload ssl certification .p12 format file, I get below error

```
403 Forbidden Error - We're not sure you're supposed to be here...
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I am sure my p12 file is correct as I have used the same file in Google Cloud Platform and it worked there. So I don't see the problem in it.

I have created the Developer account in Urban Airship and upgraded the free trial of 45 days.

Please suggest what should I do to upload p12 file

Comment: How about contacting their support?

Comment: Lol, this guys don't even give the information about the error. You really should not be there. Contact support.

Comment: I am sure they won't give proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

An http error with code 403 - Forbidden means just that. You are trying to access a resource to which access is forbidden. This is not a problem with authentication that you could solve, it is forbidden for everyone. Nobody is allowed to go there. Not ever. There's no way around this. It is not a problem with the file you are trying to upload, not a problem with your account, it is the fact that you are trying to access a resource that nobody will ever be allowed to access.

The only way to not get this code is to go to a different URL that you are allowed to access.